# io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable - variable name is the same

Tags: python, python-3.x

So this is my code snippet. I keep getting the error "io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable"

```
outputfile = open("output.txt")
for line in lines:
    outputfile.write(line)

outputfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, `open()` opens files for reading, not writing.  To open a file for writing, you need to specify `'w'` as the mode:

```
outputfile = open("output.txt", 'w')
```